# .o vs .out in C

Tags: c, file, output

I compile C code using gcc in a debian system. Normally, I would use gcc file.c -o file.out. But I mistakenly typed gcc file.c -o file.o .

When, running ./file.o it still worked!

What is this .o file, is it same as .out?

Comment: The file is extension is only a *convention*. Compare the binary contents to confirm.

Comment: What you name the file makes no difference. You could use `-o file.banana` and it would still be the same file.

Comment: You should be using `make` rather than calling `gcc` yourself.

Comment: @o11c I disagree somewhat. Until they have done enough compiling from the command line to familiarize themselves with the needed compiler and linker options, using `make` doesn't help. Once familiarized with the needed compiler and linker options, then `make` can provide a benefit. Even then, for single source projects (as most education projects are), there is little benefit using `make`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By convention, the `.o` suffix is the `object` code.  GCC and other compilers actually run through several steps when compiling.  At a high level, it looks like this:

1. pre-processor.  This resolves your `#define` and `#include` and other `#...` macros.  This step is rarely output to a file - it's almost universally passed directly into the next step.
2. Object compilation.  The lines of code are transformed into machine code and symbol tables.  The symbol tables are not yet linked into an executable.  For larger programs, this is an intermediate output when you are compiling multiple files which may have dependencies on one another.
3. Linking. The symbols in the object code are now resolved to the actual memory locations or call points to provide a fully-fledged executable.

yes, this is a simplified view that leaves out optimizations, debugging symbols, stripping, library linkages and a few other steps, but those could also be considered sub-steps in the compilation process.

By convention:

- C files are named `.c` and `.h`
- C++: `.cpp` and `.hpp` or `.c++` and `.h++`
- Object files are named `.o`.
- Fortran is `.f`.
- Assembly is `.as`.
- Static libraries are `.a` on UNIX and `.lib` on Windows
- Dynamic libraries are `.so` on UNIX and `.dll` on Windows
- Executables generally have no extension on UNIX, and `.exe` on Windows, though there is a default of `a.out` for linked C and C++ programs that haven't specified an output name.

There is no reason or requirement for the above, except that's what has been done since the '70s and that's what programmers expect.

Answer (score 7):

`.o` files are the object files compiled from a source code by a compiler. These are raw binary files and are not yet linked with any platform dependent library. You can't just run a `.o` file on your system.

```
gcc -c program.c
```

(Notice the `-c flag` is telling the compiler only to compile.)
will produce a binary file `program.o` which you cannot be run on your platform immediately.You need to link it with `crt objects`, and the `dynamic libraries` for the platform.

For my linux system.

```
ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o program.o -lc /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

Now this will create an executable file `a.out` which you could execute right from the console.

however when you run

```
gcc program.c
```

The compiler performs the linking part for you and spits out a `a.out` executable file.

Conclusion: Compilers generates `.o` object files by compiling the source code which then needs to be linked with platform's object files and libraries to generate the executable `.out` object file for that platform, a process called linking.

Some references:
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out 
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0 
[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file 
[4] http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Edit:
the -o flag is used place the output of compiler in the specified file.
This is the excerpt from the manual.

-o ***file***

> Place output in file ***file***.  This applies to whatever sort of
> output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an
> object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
>
> ```
>        If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file
>        in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its
>        assembler file in source.s, a precompiled header file in
>        source.suffix.gch, and all preprocessed C source on standard
>        output.
> ```

The extension does not really matter here.

> Filesystems for UNIX-like operating systems do not separate the
> extension metadata from the rest of the file name. The dot character
> is just another character in the main filename.
> It is mostly intended for the human user. It is more common, especially
> in binary files, for the file itself to contain internal metadata
> describing its contents.

Both the .o and .out or any extension files would contain same binary output if they are coming from the same compile operation.

Comment: All correct, but he was asking in the context of `gcc -o file.o file.c` and `gcc file` where both `file.o` and `out` would be the same executable. So you may address that as well.

Comment: Noob question: In your example, why use dynamic linking? Do we need dynamic linking even if the executable doesn't use any dynamic library(.so file)? Or, are there any "default" dynamic libraries that must be dynamically linked for every executable, even if it's just a "hello world" program?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `gcc` without options that tell it to produce a different type of output (such as `-c` to create object files  `-S` to create assembly files), it will create an executable file. It does so regardless of what name with what extension you give that file. So in your case `file.o` is an executable file, no different than any other executable file regardless of its extension.

By convention the `.o` extension is for object files and executable files should have no extension (even though the default name is `a.out`, which has the `.out` extension, that extension is not commonly used). You broke than convention by naming the file `.o`, but, other than being confusing, that's of no practical consequence.

Naming your file `.o` does not tell `gcc` that it should create an object file. Only the `-c` option does that. Since you did not pass that option, you did not create an object file.

Comment: Aren't executable files a subset of object files?